# How to group ages in specific range using clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a list which has the age of persons like (12,23,34,33,34,45,56...) almost 200 numbers. I want to group them (10-20)(21-30)(31-40)....(91-100)age groups seperately.

How do I do it in clojure.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show some code? What your list looks like, how you represent ‘age’, how you’re trying to group the age brackets and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation, the key functions are [`group-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) and [`quot`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quot):

```
(defn group-by-tens [numbers]
  (->> numbers (group-by #(quot % 10))
    (sort-by first)
    (map second)))
```

Example:

```
(group-by-tens [15 28 35 6 9 37 33 47 11 38 4 27 49 47 38 20 36 49 27 30])
=> ([6 9 4] [15 11] [28 27 20 27] [35 37 33 38 38 36 30] [47 49 47 49])
```

Comment: Tip: run `(apropos "group")` in the REPL, you'll see `clojure.core/group-by` pop up.

Comment: yeah...tried it..was really helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

also, if your age values are sorted (like in the example from your question), you can just partition them (or otherwise sort and partition):

```
user> (partition-by #(quot % 10) 
                    [1 2 3 4 10 12 16 23 27 29 33 34 45 59 71 72])
;;=> ((1 2 3 4) (10 12 16) (23 27 29) (33 34) (45) (59) (71 72))
```